# What is the iOS simulator Command symbol on Touch Bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am running the iOS simulator, using the default Touch Bar controls. I tried `"Customize Touch Bar..."`, but that didn't have the Command icon in the list of controls.

It seems like I can toggle it, and it turns blue when toggled.

What does the 5<sup>th</sup> symbol/icon in the middle group do?

[image: Touch Bar image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It toggles whether or not keyboard shortcuts are intercepted by Simulator.app or sent to the simulated device.

Comment: When you say that keyboard shortcuts could be sent to the simulated device, what do you mean? Why is that different from shortcuts going directly to the simulator app?

Comment: You may have missed my previous question in my comment above, but if you could let me know, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Consider cmd-q.  Do you want that to quit Simulator.app running on your mac, or do you want those key events to be delivered to the simulated device such that the keystroke is delivered to your app?

Comment: Ok, I understand exactly what you mean now :)